# Bash script: spawning multiple processes issues

Tags: bash, scripting, wait, backticks

So i am writing a script to call a process 365 times and they should run in 10 batches, so this is something i wrote but there are multiple issues -
1. the log message is not getting written to the log file, i see the error message in err file
2. there is this "Command not found" error I keep getting from the script for the line process.
3. even if the command doesnt succeed, still it doesn't print FAIL but prints success

```
#!/bin/bash

set -m
FAIL=0

for i in {1..10}
do
  waitPIDS=()
  j=$i
  while [ $j -lt 366 ]; do

  exec 1>logfile
  exec 2>errorfile

 `process $j &`

  waitPIDS[${#waitPIDS[@]}]=$!
  j=$[$j+1]

done

for jpid in "${waitPIDS[@]}"
do
  echo $jpid
  wait $jpid
  if [[ $? != 0 ]] ; then
    echo "fail"
  else
    echo "success"
  fi
done

done
```

What is wrong with it ?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least, this line:

```
 `process $j &`
```

Shouldn't have any backticks in it.  You probably just want:

```
 process $j &
```

Besides that, you're overwriting your log files instead of appending to them; is that intended?

Comment: Thanks yes the backtick was the issue, but I thought any process from bash script should run under backtick .
yes i forgot to add $j in log, as i am creating a log for every instance.